# Let $F/\mathbb{Q}$ be a degree 4 extension, NOT Galois. Prove that the Galois closure of $F$ has Galois group either $S_4, A_4$ or $D_8$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

The question is as the title states. So if $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some alpha that satisfies a degree 4 polynomial $p(x)$, then we are looking for the splitting field of $p(x)$? I'm not sure what to work with, given the information...

Comment: The Galois closure is generated by *all* four roots of $p(X)$ and acts transitively on these roots. What are the transitive subgroups of $S_4$? Which one is excluded?

Answer (score 5):

You have a good start: by the primitive element theorem, we know that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)$ for some $\alpha$ whose minimal polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Q}[x]$ is of degree $4$. Let's denote the splitting field of $p$ by $L$.

What do we know about the extension $L/\mathbb{Q}$?

- it is a Galois extension, since it is a splitting field, and characteristic $0$ implies separable
- each element of the Galois group $G=\mathrm{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ is determined by how it permutes the four roots of $p$, and therefore $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $S_4$
- $L$ **strictly** contains $K$ and $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=4$, and $G\subseteq S_4$ implies $[L:\mathbb{Q}]$ divides $24$, so we must have $[L:\mathbb{Q}]\in\{8,12,24\}$

Looking at the subgroups of $S_4$ ([groupprops link](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_structure_of_symmetric_group%3aS4)), the only possibilities are $D_8$, $A_4$, and $S_4$.

Comment: Thank you so much. The next part is $G = D_8 \iff F$ contains a quadratic extension. IS this the correct procedure? Anything simpler? Let $E = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})$. Then $$F=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{D})(\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{D}}) = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{a+b\sqrt{D}})$$ for a nonsquare $a+b\sqrt{D} = \beta$. The minimal polynomial of $F/\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^4 - 2ax^2 +a^2 - b^2D$, with resolvent cubic $x^3 + 4ax^2 + 4b^2Dx$, where you can factor an $x$, and thus it cannot be $S_4$ or $A_4$, then it is $D_8$.

Comment: That might be correct, but I don't know about resolvent cubics unfortunately. Certainly we can rule out $A_4$ because it has no subgroup of index $2$.